# React Redux with React Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-table

I'm trying to learn react table and react redux, which I can't search for something that references of them both using together, can someone provide an example that I can reference so I can implement it myself? TIA

This is my component so far, which doesnt give me an error and gets the redux state fine but does not render the data on the table.

```
function ResidentTable({ history }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  const residentList = useSelector(state => state.residentList);
  const { loading, error, residents } = residentList;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo || !userInfo.isAdmin) {
      history.push('/login');
    } else {
      dispatch(listResidents());
    }
  }, [dispatch, history]);

  const columns = useMemo(() => RESIDENT_COLUMNS, []);
  const data = useMemo(() => residents, []);
  const tableInstance = useTable(
    { columns, data },
    useFilters,
    useGlobalFilter,
    useSortBy,
    usePagination
  );
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    page,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    canNextPage,
    canPreviousPage,
    prepareRow,
  } = tableInstance;

  return (
    <Box p="2rem 8rem">
      <ModalResident />
      <Table
        size="lg"
        variant="striped"
        colorScheme="blackAlpha"
        {...getTableProps()}
      >
        <TableCaption placement="top">
          <Heading>Metroville Residents List</Heading>
        </TableCaption>
        <Thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <Tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <Th
                  fontSize="1.2rem"
                  fontFamily="Raleway"
                  {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}
                >
                  {column.render('Header')}
                  <Text as="span">
                    {column.isSorted ? (
                      column.isSortedDesc ? (
                        <ChevronDownIcon />
                      ) : (
                        <ChevronUpIcon />
                      )
                    ) : (
                      ''
                    )}
                  </Text>
                  <Box onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
                    {column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}
                  </Box>
                </Th>
              ))}
            </Tr>
          ))}
        </Thead>
        <Tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <Tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return (
                    <Td
                      fontSize="1 rem"
                      fontFamily="Raleway"
                      {...cell.getCellProps()}
                    >
                      {cell.render('Cell')}
                    </Td>
                  );
                })}
              </Tr>
            );
          })}
        </Tbody>
      </Table>
      <Flex justify="space-between" my="1rem">
        <Button disabled={!canPreviousPage} onClick={() => previousPage()}>
          <ArrowBackIcon />
          Prev
        </Button>
        <Button disabled={!canNextPage} onClick={() => nextPage()}>
          Next
          <ArrowForwardIcon />
        </Button>
      </Flex>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With experimentations and so many errors after, I refactored my code to be more uniformed and readable and made it work. I seperated the react-table component to another one so I can reuse it for other tables and just added the loading so it will  wait for the redux state to load before rendering it empty or erroring it out.

```
function ResidentTable({ history }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const residentList = useSelector(state => state.residentList);
  const { loading, error, residents } = residentList;

  const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo || !userInfo.isAdmin) {
      history.push('/login');
    } else {
      dispatch(listResidents());
    }
  }, [dispatch, history, userInfo]);

  const columns = useMemo(() => RESIDENT_COLUMNS, []);
  const data = useMemo(() => residents, [residents]);

  return (
    <Box p="2rem 8rem">
      <ModalResident />
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message status="error">{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <BaseTable data={data} columns={columns} />
      )}
    </Box>
  );
}
```